# Best method to intersect many arrays

Tags: php, arrays, math, intersection

I have a 2 dimensional array (`$a`), the first dimensional has 600 elements, the second dimension can have from 1k to 10k elements. Something like:

```
$a[0] = array(4 => true, 10 => true, 18 => true...);
$a[1] = array(6 => true, 10 => true, 73 => true...);
$a[599] = array(106 => true, 293 => true, 297 => true...);
```

I need to save in a file the `$intersection` of each of those 600 elements with each other 5x. Something like this:

```
for ($i=0;$i<=599;$i++) {

    for ($j=$i+1;$j<=599;$j++) {

        for ($k=$j+1;$k<=599;$k++) {

            for ($p=$k+1;$p<=599;$p++) {

                for ($m=$p+1;$m<=599;$m++) {

                     $intersection = array_intersect_key($a[$i], $a[$j], $a[$k], $a[$p], $a[$m]);

                }  

            }

        }
    
    }

}
```

I am using `array_intersect_key` because its much faster than `array_intersect` because it's `O(n)` vs `O(n^2)`.

That code works fine but runs pretty slow. So I made maaany other attempts which runs a little faster, something like:

```
for ($i=0;$i<=599;$i++) {

    for ($j=$i+1;$j<=599;$j++) {

        $b = array_intersect_keys($a[$i], $a[$j]);

        for ($k=$j+1;$k<=599;$k++) {
             
            $c = array_intersect_keys($b, $a[$k]);

            for ($p=$k+1;$p<=599;$p++) {

                $d = array_intersect_keys($c, $a[$p]);

                for ($m=$p+1;$m<=599;$m++) {

                     $intersection = array_intersect_key($d, $a[$m]);

                }  

            }

        }
    
    }

}
```

This runs 3x faster than the 1st code, but it's still pretty slow. I also tried creating long binary vectors like `00000011001110...` (for each 600 elements) and doing bitwise operations `&&` which works exactly like an intersect, but it's not much faster and uses a lot more memory.

So I am wondering, do you have any breakthrough suggestion? Any mathematical operation, matrix operation... that I can use? I am really tempted to recreate the C+ code of the `array_intersect_keys` because at every execution it does a lot of things that I dont need, like ordering the arrays before performing the intersection - I dont need that because I already ordered all my arrays before operations start, so that creates a big overhead. But I still dont want to go that route because it's not that simple to create a PHP extension that performs better than the native implementation.

Note: my array `$a` has all the elements already sorted and the elements in the first dimension that have less elements in the second dimension are positioned first in the array so `array_intersect_keys` works much faster because that function has to check only until reach the end of the first parameter (which is smaller in size).

**EDIT**

@user1597430 Again I appreciate all your attention and further explanations you gave me. You made me complete understand everything you said! And after that, I decided to take a shot on my own implementation of your algorithm and I think it is a little bit simpler and faster because I never need to use sort and I also make good use of array keys (instead of values). Feel free to use the algorithm below whenever you want if you ever need it, you already provided me with lots of your time!

After implementing the algorithm below I just realized one thing at the end! I can ONLY start checking the intersections/combinations after all the combinatory phase is done, and after that, I need to run another algorithm to parse the results. To me that's not possible because using 600x1000 takes already a long time and I may very well end up having to use 600x20000 (yeap, 600 x 20k) and I am pretty sure it's gonna take forever. And only after "forever" is that I will be able to check the combinations/intersections result (parse). Do you know a way in such a manner that I can already check the intersections after each computation or not having to wait ALL the combinations be generated? That's pretty sad that after taking almost 6 hours to understand and implement the algorithm below, I just came to the conclusion it wont fit my need. Dont worry, I will accept your answer if no better one come, since you already helped me a lot and I LEARNED A LOT WITH you!

```
<?php

$quantity_first_order_array = 10;
$quantity_second_order_array = 20;







$a = array();
$b = array();

for ($i=0;$i<$quantity_first_order_array;$i++) {
    
    for ($j=0;$j<$quantity_second_order_array;$j++) {
  
        //I just use `$i*2 + $j*3 + $j*$i` as a way to avoid using `rand`, dont try to make sense of this expression, it's just to avoid using `rand`.
        $a['group-' . $i][$i*2 + $j*3 + $j*$i] = true;

        $b[$i*2 + $j*3 + $j*$i] = true;

    }       
    
}



//echo "aaaa\n\n";var_dump($a);exit();



$c = array();

foreach ($b as $chave1 => $valor1) {
    
    $c[$chave1] = array();
    
    foreach ($a as $chave2 => $valor2) {
    
        if (isset($a[$chave2][$chave1])) {
            
            $c[$chave1][] = $chave2;
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

foreach ($c as $chave1 => $valor1) {
    
    if (count($c[$chave1]) < 5) {
    
        unset($c[$chave1]);
        
    }
    
}


//echo "cccc\n\n";var_dump($c);exit();




$d = array();

foreach ($c as $chave1 => $valor1) {
    
    $qntd_c_chave1 = count($c[$chave1]);
    
    for ($a1=0;$a1<$qntd_c_chave1;$a1++) {
        
        for ($a2=$a1 + 1;$a2<$qntd_c_chave1;$a2++) {
            
            for ($a3=$a2 + 1;$a3<$qntd_c_chave1;$a3++) {
                
                for ($a4=$a3 + 1;$a4<$qntd_c_chave1;$a4++) {
                    
                    for ($a5=$a4 + 1;$a5<$qntd_c_chave1;$a5++) {
                        
                        $d[$c[$chave1][$a1] . '|' . $c[$chave1][$a2] . '|' . $c[$chave1][$a3] . '|' . $c[$chave1][$a4] . '|' . $c[$chave1][$a5]][] = $chave1;
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

echo "dddd\n\n";var_dump($d);exit();


?>
```

Comment: For working code optimisations, you should post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I will do that too, thanks for suggesting. I am thinking about posting on Math too if I dont get any help here.

Comment: Can you explain your "with each other 5x"? Why 5? What exactly do you compare? And what is "slow" in your opinion, how much time the code above takes on your machine?

Comment: @user1597430 I need to intersect all the 600 elements in all permutations containing 5 elements (it's a genetic algorithm `fit` function, I will not get in details why it's 5 because it's a long story). I consider `slow` anything that is slower than I am getting now. I consider `fast`, anything which is faster than I am doing now. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I usually don't do this for free, but since you mentioned genetic algos... Hello from Foldit community.

```
<?php

# a few magic constants

define('SEQUENCE_LENGTH',           600);
define('SEQUENCE_LENGTH_SUBARRAY', 1000);

define('RAND_MIN',      0);
define('RAND_MAX', 100000);

define('MIN_SHARED_VALUES', 5);

define('FILE_OUTPUT', sys_get_temp_dir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'out.csv');


# generates a sample data for processing

$a = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < SEQUENCE_LENGTH; $i++)
{
    for ($j = 0; $j < SEQUENCE_LENGTH_SUBARRAY; $j++)
    {
        $a[$i][] = mt_rand(RAND_MIN, RAND_MAX);
    }

    $a[$i] = array_unique($a[$i]);

    sort($a[$i]);
}


# prepares a map where key indicates the number
# and value is a sequence that contains this number

$map = [];

foreach ($a as $i => $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $value)
    {
        $map[$value][$i] = $i;
    }
}

ksort($map);


# extra optimization: drop all values that don't have at least
# MIN_SHARED_VALUES (default = 5) sequences
foreach ($map as $index => $values)
{
    if (count($values) < MIN_SHARED_VALUES)
    {
        unset($map[$index]);
    }
    else
    {
        # reindex array keys - we need that later for simple
        # "for" loops that should start from "0"
        $map[$index] = array_values($map[$index]);
    }
}


$file = fopen(FILE_OUTPUT, 'w');

# permutation: generates all sequences that share the same $value
foreach ($map as $value => $array)
{
    $array_length = count($array);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $array_length; $i++)
    {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $array_length; $j++)
        {
            for ($k = $j + 1; $k < $array_length; $k++)
            {
                for ($l = $k + 1; $l < $array_length; $l++)
                {
                    for ($m = $l + 1; $m < $array_length; $m++)
                    {
                        # index indicates a group that share a $value together
                        $index = implode('-', [$array[$i], $array[$j], $array[$k], $array[$l], $array[$m]]);

                        # instead of CSV export you can use something like
                        # "$result[$index][] = $value" here, but you need
                        # tons of RAM to do that
                        fputcsv($file, [$index, $value]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fclose($file);
```

Locally script makes ~6.3 million permutations, that takes ~15s in total, 70% of the time goes to the I/O HDD operations.

You are free to play with the output method (by using linux `sort out.csv -o sorted-out.csv` on the top of your CSV file or by creating a separate file pointer for each unique `$index` sequence to dump your results - it's up to you).

Comment: My friend, I am amazed that you took a very different approach to this problem! I added a long EDIT to my question so I can better understand your code cause I didnt manage to get the output you mentioned (I am probably doing something stupid and I would be very grateful for some more of your time). Thank you so much!

Comment: I should probably explain the last step once more because it's not really obvious. The code above finds values first and only then gives you groups that share this value. That means that the same group may appear for another value later, so in the end you should sort your file (in Linux OS you can run `sort out.csv -o sorted-out.csv` to make this happen, so your groups will be grouped properly and you'll be able to get your desired result.

Comment: There's another option to make things clear for you - you can replace `file = fopen(FILE_OUTPUT, 'w');` with `$result = [];`, `fputcsv($file, [$index, $value]);` with `$result[$index][] = $value;` and remove `fclose($file);`. But don't forget to reduce `SEQUENCE_LENGTH` and `SEQUENCE_LENGTH_SUBARRAY` values or you'll become run out of RAM very soon.

Comment: So, once again: in the end of the final loop you'll receive all permutations, just not in the order you expect by default. Your task is to sort your final output by the group, not by the value. I don't know what OS are you using and what is the real output format, but there are a lot of ways to do that, pick on your own taste.

Comment: An example of what I mean: `$a = ['group1' => [1, 3, 5], 'group2' => [1, 5, 7]]` will give you a CSV file with the following lines: `group1,1`, `group2,1`, `group1,5`, `group2,5`. Just sort the file to make it `group1,1`, `group1,5`, `group2,1`, `group2,5`. If you need any specific format like `group1,1,5`, `group2,1,5` you can easily do that with a sorted file. There are also some other ways to simplify the sorting step, but I think you got the main idea.

Comment: My good friend, sorry for me taking so long to answer you. I studied your algorithm a lot and made my own implementation of it that in my head looks simpler, and in practice, runs faster. But I got into a problem that I see no way out. Could you kindly read my last edit to my question and see if you can provide me with a solution? I already thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: Uh... To answer your question properly I should understand your real task and make a research with tons of local tests. I've already spent 3 hours on your question and reached my internal limit of a free support. NP-complete tasks are usually solved by the data size optimization (by filtering the data or reducing it's physical size), data grouping (sorting or transforming the data into the form that requires less resources for processing) or CPU/memory trading (when CPU costs can be lowered by increasing memory/hdd costs and vice versa [caching]).

Comment: Thank you so much for your attention, you helped me a lot!!!

Comment: @Samul, you are welcome. Just curious: are you a kind of scientist or a student or... ?

Comment: I am retired but I worked as mechanical engineer, programmer, piano teacher and now I do freelance on AI to solve some supermarkets problem, and I am always amazed how clever people come to great ideas (like you did) in a surprising way!